# Как сделать select box в activeadmin для поля которое не существует в данной таблице

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Задача следующая:
Есть таблица адресов, которая связана с районами, которые в свою очередь связаны с городами. Прямой связи адреса-города нет. В таблице адресов отсутствует поле города и нет в нем необходимости, но нужно сделать 2 селект бокса, в одном выбирать город, во втором все районы этого города.
Как сделать 2 связанных селекта я нашел [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11603188), но не понимаю как сделать инпут для поля которое не существует.

**Update**

```
Address model:
  belongs_to :district
District model:
  has_many :addresses
  belongs_to :city
Cities model:
  has_many :districts
```

Comment: `has_many` `:through` не катит?

Comment: совсем не понимаю как это использовать при таких связях, может быть они некорректны для такой задачи?

Comment: Ну, как обычно, `has_many :addresses, through: :districts` в `City`. Возможно, я просто не совсем понимаю вашу задачу; а может, вы не знаете типовых решений. Я допускаю оба варианта.

Comment: Тогда получаю ошибку    ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `city' for #<Address:0x007ff910fea428>): , если в Activeadmin address.rb добавить    f.input :city

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Конкретно в моем случае оказалось, что нет нужды использовать `has_many :addresses, through: :districts в City`

Address.rb

```
f.render 'admin/city_district'
f.input :district
```

_city_district.html.erb

```
    <li class="select input optional">
    <%= label_tag :city,"City", class: "label" %>
    <%= select_tag :city, options_from_collection_for_select(City.all, "id", "name"), remote: true, id: 'address_city' %>
</li>
```

district_selection.coffee

```
jQuery ->
  districts = $('#address_district_id').html()
  $('#address_city').change ->
    city_id = $('#address_city :selected').val()
    $('#address_district_id').empty()
    $('#address_district_id').prepend('<option>Выберите район</option>')
    getURL = (url) ->
      response = $.parseJSON($.ajax(
        type: 'GET'
        url: url
        cache: true
        async: false).responseText)
      for obj of response
        $('#address_district_id').append('<option value='+response[obj].id+'>'+response[obj].name+'</option>')
    getURL('/api/districts?city_select=' + city_id)
```

active-admin.rb

```
config.register_javascript 'district_selection.js'
```

Answer (score 1):

Помимо `has_many :addresses, through: :districts в City` добавил

```
delegate :city, :to => :district, :allow_nil => true
```

и заработало как было задумано.